# Type classes. families and polymorphism

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, ghc, emulation

I'm trying to write a fairly straightforward processor emulator and am trying to separate the actual processor from its memory interface. For example, an old TRS-80 has 12K of ROM and can be configured with a total of 16, 32 or 48K of total RAM. My initial idea for the memory system was a type class:

```hs
class MemorySystem memInternals addrType wordType where
  -- | General memory fetch. This always returns a 'wordType' value,
  -- even if the system's memory internals are byte addressable.
  mfetch :: addrType       -- ^ The address from which the instruction will be fetched
         -> memInternals   -- ^ The memory system
         -> wordType       -- ^ The fetched word

  -- | Fetch a block of words from the memory system
  mfetchN :: ( Unbox wordType
             ) =>
             addrType      -- ^ The address from which the instruction will be fetched
          -> Int           -- ^ Number of words to fetch
          -> memInternals  -- ^ The memory system
          -> Vector wordType -- ^ The words fetched
```

Clarification: the point of `MemorySystem` is to allow an instruction decoder, e.g., a Z80 instruction decoder in the case of a TRS-80, to operate independently of its memory interface, such that all the decoder need do is call `mfetch` for the next instruction and its operands. Hence, `memInternals` is a type that implements an interface to a memory system specified partially by the type class functions.

How is the best way of constraining `addrType` and `wordType` while allowing `memInterals` to be polymorphic, i.e., allowing `memInternals` to represent different memory configurations. I'm finding myself adding contexts to functions that look like:

```hs
foo :: ( MemorySystem memSys Word16 Word8) =>
    -> memSys
    -> Word16
    -> Word16
bar :: ( MemorySystem memSys Word16 Word8) =>
    -> memSys
    -> Word16
    -> Word8
bar mem pc = ...
  -- bar calls foo -> rigid type variable error...
```

which leads to a lot of rigid type variable errors in ghc.

Is there a better way of expressing a `MemorySystem` that leads to the "right type" of polymorphism in `memInternals` such that a family of memory interfaces can be properly represented (and acted upon via a type class or family)?

Comment: The question is unclear about what kind of polymorphism you want ? Also you problem about rigid type variable is not very clear. Maybe you should add more code and error you are getting.

Comment: @user1902082 you might be looking for functional dependencies (changing your class to `class MemorySystem memInternals addrType wordType | memInternals -> addrType wordType`) so that your address and word type are uniquely determined by `memInternals` but it's not clear what you're looking to do

Comment: @jberryman: That's partially what I'm looking for. 

There's the other part, which effectively would implement the polymorphism of `memInternals` across various memory configurations, such that a Z80 instruction decoder only has to invoke `mfetch` to get the next instruction or opcode. However, using `MemorySystem` as a constraint leads to the rigid type variable problem.

Maybe I'm looking for lexical type variables?

Comment: Before making this a type class, try to design records holding the different functions you want.  Type classes are an "ad hoc" way to generalize these and make these records available via contraints.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, you can try using associated type families.  But it looks like your current use case is well served by the data type instead of the type class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, RankNTypes #-}
import Data.Vector.Unboxed

class MemorySystem memInternals where
  type AddrType memInternals
  type WordType memInternals

  mfetch :: memInternals
         -> AddrType memInternals
         -> AddrType wordType

  mfetchN :: Unbox wordType
          => memInternals
          -> AddrType memInternals
          -> Int
          -> Vector wordType

-- The record type may be more flexible and appropriate here
data MemorySystem addrType wordType = MemorySystem {
    mfetch :: addrType -> wordType
  , mfetchN :: Unbox wordType => addrType -> Int -> Vector wordType
  }
```

See how the type class has only functions that take the type parameter `memInternals` only once and as the first argument?  This seems equivalent to the record approach.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. Understanding just set in.

Comment: The only drawback of the record approach would be the need to wrap or embed the memory system internals (e.g., a generic model of the Z80's memory vs. a more specific TRS-80 version), but it looks workable. OTOH, records imply interesting things with lenses (I like Control.Lens, personally).

Answer (score 0):

The record approach does work best, at least for proper separation of concerns. Here's what works for me:

```
data (Unbox wordType) => MemorySystem addrType wordType memSys =
  MemorySystem
  { _mfetch :: addrType -> wordType
  , _ mfetchN :: addrType -> Int -> Vector wordType
  , _memInternals = memSys
  }
```

(Note that `memInternals` can be accessed from within `mfetch` and `mfetchN`, so no need to duplicate it as a parameter to those two functions.) It's then possible to create lenses for this record, e.g., using `Control.Lens` and `makeLenses`. It also permits defining types like:

```
import Data.Word
import Data.Int

type Z80addr = Word16
type Z80word = Word8
type Z80memory memConfig = MemorySystem Z80addr Z80word memConfig
```

that permit a polymorphic memory configuration. Many thanks to Chris for the suggestion -- I'm not sure why I got wrapped around the proverbial axle thinking in terms of type families.